# How to flush collection in couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

The way we have flush operation for buckets can we also do similar for collection in couchbase?
is there any alternate to drop and recreate the collection if we want to delete all data from the collection? what will be optimal approach purging data from collection?

Comment: Do you want to do this from an SDK? Have you tried "drop collection" and then "create collection"? Those should be available from the SDK.

Comment: @MatthewGroves would you share some sample spring application link if possible.

Comment: Sorry, I'm no Java dev. It probably wouldn't involve Spring, though, it would involve using the Couchbase Java SDK directly. Here's the relevant API docs: https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client/com/couchbase/client/java/manager/collection/CollectionManager.html

Answer (score 0):

getCluster() exposes the cluster of the Java SDK.

repository.getOperations().getCouchbaseClientFactory().getCluster().buckets().flushBucket(bucketName)